# Finding intersections on line using ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcpy

I have a line feature class in ArcMap, as shown on the picture. This is a simple line layer, that was previously generated with extend to line tool.

Now I would like to know the coordinates of the intersections. I would like to get it via python, because I need to integrate this step to a script tool.

[image: intersection]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes using [Intersect](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm) tool with `output_type="POINT"` and a [SearchCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm):

```
import arcpy
lines=r"C:\test.gdb\Lines" #Change to match your data
tempintersections=r"in_memory\intersections"
arcpy.Intersect_analysis(in_features=lines, out_feature_class=tempintersections, output_type="POINT")

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tempintersections,"SHAPE@XY") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        x,y = row[0]
        print x,y
```

Will for example output:

```
523956.9342 6478001.4342
524034.1428 6478019.8971
```